# Getting issue while uploading ipa in App store using application loader

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, xcode5.1

[image][image]I am getting some issue like attached in screen shots. I dont know why its coming as i have given the bundle name valid for both provisional profile and to my application in xcode.

Comment: Have you talked to Apple?  And what do you have set as the minimum iOS version?  Also, please edit the question so the errors are included in text, not just image, for Search Engine purposes.

Comment: i have set minimum ios version to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App store Rejects the ipa file not updated in xcode 5.1.1 since 15th May 2014. Just need to update xcode 5.1 to 5.1.1.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a